# How to select record which are not between two time-Seconds range in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have one Oracle table in which ORACLE time column stored in following format.

for 12 AM -  0

for 1 AM - 3600

for 2 AM - 7200
.
.
.

for 23 PM  82800

i.e. if time is 3 AM then it will be stored as 10800
if time is 11 PM then it will be stored as 82800.

Now I want to select records which are not between 11 PM to 3 AM.

```
SELECT TIMECol
FROM MyTable
WHERE IBS_To_Time(TimeCol) NOT BETWEEN IBS_To_Time(10800) AND IBS_To_Time(82800)
```

IBS_To_Time will Converts seconds to 'HH:MM:SS' format
But this query does not display expected result.
Please help for same. What should be the optimized and best approach.

Comment: what's `IBS_To_Time` doing?

Comment: @Sebas  it gives me HH:MM:SS format

Comment: do you need that for that thing to work? It would work fine with plain number of seconds too.

Comment: not mandatory.
But still not working

Comment: Would be good to have an extract of your data. There's nothing simpler than a between and 2 numbers. Issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: I will upload extract tomorrow. It was not available with me now.

Comment: Does yesterdays 11 PM and todays 3 AM create any prob?

Comment: [Here is one of the approaches](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0c3a/1). But I really see no point in converting time represented in seconds to `HH:MI:SS` format if you use this juts to filter out data, You can easily use `where TimeCol not between 10800 and 82800 `

Answer (score 1):

So it means you want to select records which are between 3am to 11 pm (excluding)

```
select timecol from mytable
where timecol between 10800+1 and 82800-1
```

Comment: No, I want to select records after 3 AM and before 11 PM.

Comment: @Constant Learner , so this is exactly what I said!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert TIMECol to seconds and deal with it in that fashion in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT to_number(to_char(TIMECol,'sssss')) timecol_as_seconds
  FROM MyTable
```

Comment: As I understood, OP already has values  in `TIMECol` column in seconds.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I took Time column to imply a date field.  If that is the case there is no benefit in converting it to a formatted time string to do time comparisons.  OP's results are probably getting thrown off by times on different days.

Comment: `there is no benefit in converting it to a formatted time string` quite so.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ibs_to_time(TIMECol)
FROM MyTable
WHERE ( to_number(TIMECol)  NOT BETWEEN 0 AND  10400 ) AND  (to_number(TIMECol)  NOT BETWEEN 82800 AND  86400)
```